# " (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created " AGAIN

Tags: python, python-3.x, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I tried making this simple opencv2 code on my macbook when this GStreamer Pipeline error showed up. This question has been raised many times previously, but none seemed to be solving this error to me.

```
import cv2

# Open video capture
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Change to the appropriate video source if needed

while True:
    # Read a frame from the video stream
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if not ret:
    break

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('Video Capture', frame)

    # Exit loop on 'q' key press
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release video capture and close windows
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My mac's in-built camera is working with other apps. I tried re-installing, and lot many steps but none worked either